# Which operation is more expensive?Order by or group by?

Tags: sql

Which operation is more expensive?Order by or group by?

Comment: order by and group by are 2 completely different operations, thus your question doesnt makke sense

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the algorithm deployed.

However, in some situations there is a definite answer: e.g. in MySQL.

MySQL does not use a hash-based group by algorithm, but always a sort based one. That means, in MySQL, a `group by` will essentially execute an `order by` first and then do the grouping. Consequently, `group by` is more expensive than `order by` in current MySQL releases.

However, many other databases also consider using a hash table for the `group by` — in this case `group by` could also be faster than `order by` (as there is no hash-based sort algorithm).

See also:

- https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping

Answer (score 0):

**IT DEPENDS:**

Sorting is a very resource intensive operation

If an index is used it's due to the way indexes stores data 
(*the usage of indexes is to avoid the* **sorting operations** *to satisfy an
order by clause*).Otherwise it needs a fair amount of CPU time, but the main problem is that the database must temporarily *buffer the results*.

Hope you got the answer :)